# Scalacheck generate Gen.alphastr with the same length

Tags: scalacheck

I need to generate strings with the same length. I can't realize how. Many thanks

```scala
val s = for {
  x <- Gen.alphaStr
} yield ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

example code:

```scala
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll    

// strGen generates a fixed length random string
val strGen = (n: Int) => Gen.listOfN(n, Gen.alphaChar).map(_.mkString)

val fixedLengthStr = forAll(strGen(10)){ s =>
  s.length == 10
}

fixedLengthStr.check
```

to inspect a generated string use:

```scala
strGen(5).sample
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a `suchThat(f: T => Boolean): Gen[T] = new Gen[T]` on Gen, so could be used like

```scala
val stringShorterThan = (n: Int) => Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(s => s.length <= n)
val string64 = stringShorterThan(64)
```

Comment: Such a generator would discard many values because of the use of `suchThat`

Comment: You'd be better off just truncating the string `Gen.alphaStr..map(str => if (str.length <= max) str else str.substring(0,max))`